Generalization of digamma function
The digamma function has the following functional relation.
$$
\psi(z+1) = \psi(z) + \frac{1}{z}
$$
Can this be generalized? For $\alpha > 0$, I am interested to know if there is a family of functions that satisfy
$$
\alpha \psi_{\alpha}(z+1) = \psi_{\alpha}(z) + \frac{1}{z}
$$
and with the condition $\psi_1(z) = \psi(z)$. Such a function would be handy in doing some contour integrations involving exponentials.

q-Polygamma Functions.

Thanks, but the functional relation that I got using the q-Polygamma Functions is
$
\psi_q(z+1) = \psi_q(z) + \frac{\ln q}{1 - q^{-z}}
$

Following the Dirichlet integral representation, define
$$
\psi_\alpha(z) = \int_0^\infty \left[\alpha^{-z} e^{-t+\alpha-1} - \left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^z \right] \frac{dt}{t+1-\alpha}
$$
Note that $t=\alpha-1$ is a removable singularity, since
$$
\lim_{t \to \alpha-1} \left[\alpha^{-z} e^{-t+\alpha-1} - \left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^z \right] \frac{1}{t+1-\alpha} \\
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 
\left[ \alpha^{-z} e^{-\epsilon} - (\alpha+\epsilon)^{-z} \right] \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
= \alpha^{-z} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 
\left[ e^{-\epsilon} - (1+\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha})^{-z} \right] \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
= \alpha^{-z} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 
\left[ (1-\epsilon) - (1-z\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}) \right] \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
= \alpha^{-z} \left( \frac{z}{\alpha}-1 \right)
$$
Then
$$
\alpha \psi_\alpha(z+1) = \int_0^\infty \left[ \alpha^{-z} e^{-t+\alpha-1} - \alpha \left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^{z+1} \right] \frac{dt}{t+1-\alpha}
$$
Taking the difference,
$$
\alpha \psi_\alpha(z+1) - \psi_\alpha(z) \\
= \int_0^\infty \left[-\frac{\alpha}{t+1} + 1 \right] \left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^z \frac{dt}{t+1-\alpha} \\
= \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^{z+1} dt \\
= \frac{1}{z}
$$
